# Probability Question Involving 3 Events

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

> In a factory there are three types of products, are made every day
>
> It's known that `30% are product A`, `10% are product B` and `50% are product C`
>
> It's also known that only `70% of A`, `40% of B` and `70% of C`, are ok
>   What is the probability that all 3 products of a day are all rejected? And what is the probability that all products of a day are all approved?
>    Can you help me solving or at least understading how to approach this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the set of $3$ products as a string (e.g. ABB). Let $P$ be the probability that any one product in this set will be rejected, which can be calculated as follows:

$$P=P(A)\cdot P(\text{A is rejected}) +P(B)\cdot P(\text{B is rejected})+  P(C)\cdot P(\text{C is rejected})
\\ = 0.30 \cdot 0.10 + 0.20\cdot 0.40 + 0.50\cdot 0.20 \\ = 0.12$$

Now, since we need **all** three products to be rejected, we need to multiply this probability three times. Hence, the answer is $P^3 = 0.001728$. Can you do the second part yourself now?

Comment: Yes Absolutely! Tyvm